# Why ASP.NET Core DI knows how to resolve ILogger<T>, but not ILogger?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core

If class T contains dependency on ILogger, dependency is resolved:

```
public class Foo
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public Foo(ILogger<Foo> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

but the following does not work, as `logger` will be null:

```
public class Foo
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public Foo(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Logging adds the following services to DI

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
```

and `Logger<>` depends on `ILoggerFactory` from DI.

For your second scenario you would need to inject ILoggerFactory instead of ILogger.

```
public Foo(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("logger name here");
}
```

Comment: Don't inject ILoggerFactory. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345161/should-i-take-ilogger-iloggert-iloggerfactory-or-iloggerprovider-for-a-libra

Answer (score 2):

Your first scenerio works because `ILogger<>` inherits from `ILogger`([see source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/ILoggerOfT.cs))

```
public interface ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger
{

}
```

But as @KiranChalla said, in the `LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions` `ILogger<>` is registered(not `ILogger`) so your second scenerio does not work.