# Map ILogger to Serilog's Logger after ASP.NET Core 2 logging update

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

From [@nblumhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138206/nicholas-blumhardt)'s [post](https://nblumhardt.com/2017/08/use-serilog/):

> You can then go ahead and delete any other logger configuration that’s hanging around: there’s no need for a "Logging" section in appsettings.json, no AddLogging() anywhere, and no configuration through ILoggerFactory in Startup.cs.

I am getting an exception when `using Serilog;` and `ILogger` in my controller.

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public CustomersController(ILogger logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Results in:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Serilog.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'Customers.Api.Controllers.CustomersController'.

Would I still need to provide some information to DI in the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method?

My Program class, to my knowledge, follows instructions in the post.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change expected type from `ILogger logger` to `ILogger<CustomersController>` logger:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public CustomersController(ILogger<CustomersController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I reset my edits to test this and it worked. Do we know why? :-)

Comment: @leon look into [Why ASP.NET Core DI knows how to resolve ILogger<T>, but not ILogger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255053/why-asp-net-core-di-knows-how-to-resolve-iloggert-but-not-ilogger)

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative, if you still wish to use Serilog's own `ILogger` rather than ASP.NET Core's `ILogger<T>`, is to register the Serilog logger with your IoC container.

There's an integration for Autofac that does this at https://github.com/nblumhardt/autofac-serilog-integration, other containers may have integration packages out there, too.

Answer (score -3):

You can follow the below code for use.

```
//using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
            //Logger for File
            loggerFactory.AddFile("FilePath/FileName-{Date}.txt");

        }
    }

    //Add following code into Controller:

    private readonly ILogger<ControllerName> _log;

    public ControllerConstructor(ILogger<ControllerName>logger)
     {
          _log = logger;
     }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetExample()
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO:Log Informationenter code here
            _log.LogInformatio("LogInformation");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
             //TODO: Log Exception
             _log.LogError(exception, exception.Message + "\n\n");
        } 
        return view("viewName");
    }
```