# No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' has been registered

Tags: asp.net-core

Created a blank ASP.NET Core 2.0 application.
In Startup.cs, would like to log incoming requests. So in configure method, I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger logger)
  {    
      app.Use(next =>
        {
            return async context =>
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Incoming request");
                await next(context);
                logger.LogInformation("Outgoing response");
            };
        });
```

However, when I build the project, its complaining

```
 An error occurred while starting the application.
 InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' has been registered.
```

Why and how should I register this service? Had it been my interface, it would have still made sense to do

```
services.AddScope
```

in ConfigureServices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why ASP.NET Core DI knows how to resolve ILogger<T>, but not ILogger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255053/why-asp-net-core-di-knows-how-to-resolve-iloggert-but-not-ilogger)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

ILogger is always of a type, try change it like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
  {    
      app.Use(next =>
        {
            return async context =>
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Incoming request");
                await next(context);
                logger.LogInformation("Outgoing response");
            };
        });
```

Comment: If I have a Helpers class that is called from different types, like a Controller, View or another helper class, will I need different Helpers constructor for each calling type? Like `Helpers(ILogger<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller> logger, IConfiguration configuration)` and `Helpers(ILogger<AnotherHelper> logger, IConfiguration configuration)`?

Answer (score 0):

No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' has been registered

This error means that you didn't provide class name into your logger interface(instance of the interface), for example instead of:

> ILogger logger

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger logger)
  {
```

You should use:

> ILogger<Startup> logger

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
  {
```