# Asp.net core - The invoke method() doesn't call in Middleware

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

I familiar with Middleware concept and I had implemented many Middlewares on my project. And also I read [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) documentation at Microsoft docs. But this time I faced with confusing problem, Actually I wrote a simple middle to write logs per each requests.

This is my middleware class:

```
public class LoggerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, LogDbContext dbContext)
    {
        var logInfo = await Logger.InitiateLogging(httpContext, dbContext);
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Logger.AddException(httpContext, ex, true);
        }
        finally
        {
            await Logger.PersistLog(logInfo, httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I declared an extension-method:

```
public static class LoggingMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLogger(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LoggerMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

And finally I called `UseLogger` method on `Configure` on Startup.cs.

This is my startup.cs code:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
    IOptions<BaranSettings> baranSettings)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();


    // other lines of code...
    app.UseLogger();
    // other lines of code...
}
```

**Problem**:

The problem is `LoggerMiddleware` constructor called, but the `Invoke` method doesn't call.
Does any one know what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular use case, I would strongly urge you to consider using .Net Core DI and inject an ILoggerFactory:

[Why ASP.NET Core DI knows how to resolve ILogger<T>, but not ILogger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255053/why-asp-net-core-di-knows-how-to-resolve-iloggert-but-not-ilogger)

See also:

[How to Use LoggerFactory and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging for .NET Core Logging With C#](https://stackify.com/net-core-loggerfactory-use-correctly/)